# How to index vectors with integer types (besides usize), without explicit cast?

Tags: casting, rust

There are times when indices need to be tightly packed (mesh geometry for example), where its useful to store indices as `u32` instead of `usize`.

Is there a way to index a vector in Rust without having to explicitly cast to `usize` every time? eg:

```
vector[some_u32 as usize];
```

Casting in single instances isn't a problem, its just tedious when needed frequently.

Is there a way to avoid having to cast here?

Answer (score 5):

No.

If it were your own type, you could implement `Index<u32>`, but it isn't and you can't.

If you're really, pathologically opposed to casting the index, you could write an adaptor type that does the cast, but that's getting a bit silly.

Comment: This OP. You really should be doing the cast to `usize` as early as possible and storing the value as a usize. There's no reason to try and do an operation that could possibly panic just because you want to save a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to index arrays of your own type, and you use a newtype for the index, then you can create an `Index` impl:

```
struct MyIndex(u32);
struct MyValue(u64);

impl std::ops::Index<MyIndex> for [MyValue] {
    type Output = MyValue;
    fn index(&self, idx: MyIndex) -> &MyValue {
        &self[idx.0 as usize]
    }
}
```

Now, you can index any array of `MyValue`s with `MyIndex`. Instead of using `u32` everywhere, you now have to use `MyIndex`. There's the [`newtype_derive` crate](https://crates.io/crates/newtype_derive) to help you make the `MyIndex` behave mostly like a `u32`.