# Indexing vector by a 32-bit integer

Tags: rust

In Rust, vectors are indexed using `usize`, so when writing

```
let my_vec: Vec<String> = vec!["Hello", "world"];
let index: u32 = 0;
println!("{}", my_vec[index]);
```

you get an error, as index is expected to be of type `usize`. I'm aware that this can be fixed by explicitly converting index to `usize`:

```
my_vec[index as usize]
```

but this is tedious to write. Ideally I'd simply overload the `[]` operator by implementing

```
impl<T> std::ops::Index<u32> for Vec<T> { ... }
```

but that's impossible as Rust prohibits this (as neither the trait nor struct are local). The only alternative that I can see is to create a wrapper class for `Vec`, but that would mean having to write lots of function wrappers as well. Is there any more elegant way to address this?

Comment: Well, the most elegant way would probably be to just let `index` be `usize` - either from the beginning or later, by a shadowing `let` binding.

Comment: Don't see this as being more elegant as conversion on-the-fly. I'm using plenty of different variables throughout my code, so it's not something that needs to be done only once.

Comment: If you implement both `Index<usize>` and `Index<u32>` for a custom data type, `let i = 1; foo[i]` becomes a type could not be inferred error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to index vectors with integer types (besides usize), without explicit cast?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888724/how-to-index-vectors-with-integer-types-besides-usize-without-explicit-cast)

Answer (score 5):

Without a clear use case it is difficult to recommend the best approach.

There are basically two questions here:

- do you really need indexing?
- do you really need to use `u32` for indices?

When using functional programming style, indexing is generally unnecessary as you operate on iterators instead. In this case, the fact that `Vec` only implements `Index` for `usize` really does not matter.

If your algorithm really needs indexing, then why not use `usize`? There are many ways to convert from `u32` to `usize`, converting at the last moment possible is one possibility, but there are other sites where you could do the conversion, and if you find a chokepoint (or create it) you can get away with only a handful of conversions.

At least, that's the YAGNI point of view.

---

Personally, as a type freak, I tend to wrap things around a lot. I just like to add *semantic* information, because let's face it `Vec<i32>` just doesn't mean anything.

Rust offers a simple way to create wrapper structures: `struct MyType(WrappedType);`. That's it.

Once you have your own type, adding indexing is easy. There are several ways to add other operations:

- if only a few operations make sense, then adding explicitly is best.
- if many operations are necessary, and you do not mind exposing the fact that underneath is a `Vec<X>`, then you can expose it:

  - by making it public: `struct MyType(pub WrappedType);`, users can then call `.0` to access it.
  - by implementing `AsRef` and `AsMut`, or creating a getter.
  - by implementing `Deref` and `DerefMut` (which is implicit, make sure you really want to).

Of course, breaking encapsulation can be annoying later, as it also prevents the maintenance of invariants, so I would consider it a last ditch solution.

Comment: I'm working with graphs with sometimes millions of vertices (but never more than 2^32), and for performance (particular memory usage) I prefer to store "references" to nodes as u32 rather than usize. So when traversing the graph I keep retrieving adjacent vertex "references", which I then use to look up the actual vertex object in the Vec<NodeType> object. So no easy way of avoiding conversion, and I don't use iterators so much as retrieving specific elements.

Comment: @HenningKoehler sounds like you are reimplementing [petgraph](https://github.com/bluss/petgraph).

Comment: @Shepmaster that's pretty much true - mainly doing this to gain better control over the internals for improved performance (e.g. my own tarjan implementation runs 2.5 times as fast as petgraph's). Also helps me getting up to speed with rust fundamentals.

Answer (score 4):

> I prefer to store "references" to nodes as u32 rather than usize. So when traversing the graph I keep retrieving adjacent vertex "references", which I then use to look up the actual vertex object in the Vec object

So actually you don't want `u32`, because you will never do calculations on it, and `u32` easily allows you to do math. You want an index-type that can just do indexing but whose values are immutable otherwise.

I suggest you implement something along the line of [`rustc_data_structures::indexed_vec::IndexVec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/nightly-rustc/rustc_index/vec/struct.IndexVec.html).

This custom `IndexVec` type is not only generic over the element type, but also over the index type, and thus allows you to use a `NodeId` newtype wrapper around `u32`. You'll never accidentally use a non-id `u32` to index, and you can use them just as easily as a `u32`. You don't even have to create any of these indices by calculating them from the vector length, instead the `push` method returns the index of the location where the element has just been inserted.

Comment: I guess that's essentially a wrapper type - useful link though, much better if you don't have to reinvent the wheel.